# bbPress New Topic Hook

Tags: bbpress

I'm trying to populate some custom metadata for new topics in bbPress within a class. I can successfully submit the metadata using this class, but hooking into the new topic creation doesn't seem to be working. This is the function I'm using:

```
    // Set the default status on post submit
    public function default_status() {

        // Set status to open
        update_post_meta( $this->topic_id, $this->meta_key, 1 );

    } // default_status()
```

Then in the constructor, I'm hooking into the following action:

```
add_action( 'bbp_new_topic', array( &$this, 'default_status' ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

So I finally got this working by passing the topic_id through the hook itself, like so:

```
public function default_status( $topic_id = 0 ) {

    $default_status = 1;

    // Set status to open
    update_post_meta( $topic_id, $this->meta_key, $default_status );

} // default_status()
```